# Does Xamarin Community support in-house builds? (Enterprise distribution)

Tags: xamarin.ios

Does the new, free Xamarin Community edition for Mac support making in-house builds? (Enterprise distribution)

With the previous versions, you needed the Business or Enterprise versions.

Comment: @jon-clements Why would this be off-topic? - It is not something which attracts oppinionated answers at all... it is a simply factual question on whether a specific IDE supports a specific linking option. Also seems that all my questions on this site was suddenly downvoted at the same time (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I can give you is that it depends.

With Xamarin Studio Community, it is absolutely possible to create an IPA for distribution (you can see Xamarin docs on how this is done). However, Xamarin Studio Community can only be used by developers who meet the requirements in 1(a) or (b) in the [Xamarin License](https://www.xamarin.com/license). To distribute your apps In-House(Enterprise) you would have to have an Apple Developer Enterprise Membership as explained in this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/in-house-distribution/) in order to develop and sign your app. It's unlikely that you would qualify for the Community license, AND would have an Apple Developer Enterprise membership – but it's not impossible.

Comment: In my case I do qualify for the Community license and have an Apple Developer Enterprise membership... unless I have misunderstood something about the Community license it doesn't seem that unlikely (?). Our organization has less than 250 computers, and an annual revenue less than a million dollars. I expect even larger organizations would also comply with the license terms if they distribute open source applications using Xamarin community.

Comment: Just to understand your answer correctly - do you mean that the in-house build feature is available in Xamarin Community? - or are you saying that you can create an IPA somehow using tools from Xamarin Community along with your own scripts to create in-house builds? Currently I have a Business subscriptions, where I can just click "Sign and Distribute" in Xamarin Studio, and then select Enterprise to have a file made ready for distribution. Will I be able to do the same with Xamarin Community?

Comment: @jksoegaard Yes, because you are part of the Enterprise program from Apple you can create an AdHoc certificate to sign your in-house builds.
There is nothing that will stop you creating this using the tools from Xamarin Studio Community. You should find that the workflow is the same as you are used to with Xamarin Business.

If you are ever unsure and want to test the features of Xamarin Studio Community, you can simply just sign out of your account in XS.